# is there a way to compress a NN in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

assumed I have a trained model of torch.nn.Module, and I only need it from now on for evaluation.
Is PyTorch passing my data through all the layers or is it compressing the model so that it only calculates an equivalent function?

If not, is there a way to do it in order to make the calculation faster and the model lighter in memory terms?

I have been looking on the internet for a similar question and didn't find any suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should do two things during inference: set your model to evaluation mode with `model.eval()` and use `no_grad()` (disables gradient computation). This will make your code faster and more memory-efficient.

In practice this will look like

```
model.eval() 
with torch.no_grad(): 
    #your inference code here
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options and it depends on your specific case.

One option is to convert to [TorchScript](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/torchscript_inference.html).

Another option is to do [quantization](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/quantization.html) on the model.

Third, you could perform knowledge distillation, transferring the knowledge from your existing model to a smaller one.